# How to stream Heart rate data from smartband to Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, google-fit, health-monitoring

I'm developing an app for Uni which needs to show on screen a persons heart rate preferably in real time (but its not necessary) as well as the pulse oximeter results.

The app is being developed in Kotlin and the hardware used to catch this measurements is a Huawei SmartBand 4 Pro.

I already know for a fact that in order to connect to the watch to the phone i need to use the Huawei Health App otherwise it will not be recognized by the Bluetooth adapter.

But i have no idea how to start retrieving or streaming the heart rate data from the the watch to the phone.

Will the GoogleFit API suffise for this? or would i need to use the Huawei health SDK for this.

I have no guidance for this or experience developing apps that use external sensors, and will need to deliver this app starting october so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im developing an app for Uni which needs to show on screen a persons
> heart rate preferably in real time (but its not necessary) as well as
> the pulse oximeter results.

Huawei Health Kit SDK can meet your needs. You could refer to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/app-oriented-introduction-0000001053924443).

After integrating the Health Kit SDK, your phone app can read and write the user's fitness and health data upon the data-type-specific user authorization.

You can use the health data sharing API provided by Health Kit to provide end users with a surplus of services related to running, heart rate, and sleep. For example, fitness apps can analyze users' fitness data based on user authorization, in order to provide customized fitness services and suggestions for users.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i can see that the huawei docs are written for java, would this be a problem since the entire app is built on kotlin???

Comment: hi@Juancarlord, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-health-demo-kotlin), It's HMS Health Kit Demo for kotlin.

Comment: Its also worth noting @Juancarlord  that java code can be called by Kotlin code just fine. the two are interchangeable in the same app.